# Rails + jQuery ajaxPrefilter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails 3.1 application

In my gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
```

In my assets/application.js, I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

In my application.html layout, I've included these lines

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min" %>
```

I'm using jQuery v1.6.2.

The problem is, when I try to access any page, I keep getting these errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (selector,context){return new jQuery.prototype.init(selector,context);} has no method 'ajaxPrefilter' (:3000/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1:290)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOffset' of undefined (:3000/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js?body=1:37)

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new jQuery.prototype.init(a,b)} has no method 'ajaxPrefilter'  (application.js:12)
```

What is ajaxPrefilter, and how do I fix these errors?

I've tried to reorder the javascripts with loading jquery.min.js before application.js, no luck, and I'm not sure how to inspect those errors in the js files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried those lines, but I still get the same errors:

jquery_ujs.js:290 - Uncaught TypeError: Object function (selector,context){return new jQuery.prototype.init(selector,context);} has no method 'ajaxPrefilter'
ui.geo_autocomplete.js:14 - Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'widget'
application.js:12 - Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new jQuery.prototype.init(a,b)} has no method 'ajaxPrefilter'